# Best way to include third party dependencies in Python app

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

What is the best way to distribute dependencies for an app?

Let's say I want to publish an app that depends on `SqlAlchemy` - is there a clean way to include `SqlAlchemy` in my repository without forcing the user to install it?

Answer (score 2):

Community standard is to use [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) package manager with [requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files).

E.g.

```
SQLAlchemy>=0.9.8
```

It would force installing SQLAlchemy with version above or equal to `0.9.8`.

If you want to distribute your code in standalone way, you may consider creating separate directory for 3rd party packages and extending `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/3rdpartypackages/`

Answer (score 0):

Although it would force the user to install it, I would recommend using a pip requirements file for this.
( http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files )

For this specific problem, the file could be as simple as a single line:

```
SQLAlchemy
```

As a general practice, you should specify the version number you depend upon in this file.
If you don't want a user to have to install things because you're worried about polluting their main installation, I would look in to using VirtualEnv for this ( http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/ ) - This is the recommended means of distributing dependencies for Django projects at least.